# how to receive react location.state parameter inside C# api?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using react app for Frontend changes and C# Web API as a Backend. Below is my scenario -

I am calling one API from React like below and I am also adding one state parameter in request -

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/Student/${row.id}`, state: true,}}>{row.studentName}</Link>
```

Now I have to receive this 'state' parameter in api. Below is my api code -

```
public async Task<StudentDetail> GetStudentDetail(int id)
{

}
```

Comment: how are you calling api from frontend? please add code.

Comment: @Usama, that is how we are calling the api-

<Link to={{pathname: `/Student/${row.id}`, state: true,}}>{row.studentName}</Link>

Comment: I dont think this will work, you need to use `fetch` or `axios` to send get request to api

Comment: @Usama, this is already working. I just added state parameter in react link. And I just wanted to receive it at API.

Comment: if its hitting the api then add `[HttpGet("{id}")]` on top of function

Comment: @Usama, I am already receiving the "id" parameter in api but I am not sure how to receive this "state" value (true) in api.